# PhPMyAdmin language visual error

Tags: database, phpmyadmin

i have website for flash games so when i add new game and put name( i use Bulgarian language ) i see the name in my website fine ( www.topflash-games.com ) but when i go to my Database (Mysql)i see all names like : `ÐšÑƒÐºÐ»Ð¸ Ð·Ð° ÐŸÑ€ÐµÐ¾Ð±Ð»Ð¸Ñ‡Ð°Ð½Ðµ`
In my Index.php the script is using :

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

When i go to phpMyadmin i see : Server charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8) 
and Table collation latin1_swedish_ci

so what i need to do to fix the problem with ÐšÑƒÐºÐ»Ð¸ Ð·Ð° ÐŸÑ€ÐµÐ¾Ð±Ð»Ð¸Ñ‡Ð°Ð½Ðµ`

Comment: The reason you're not getting any replies is because you are not providing enough information for anyone to guess what the problem is. At minimum, we need to know what database you are using and what its collation is.

Comment: By default Collation was : latin1_swedish_ci but i change now Collation to : CP1251_Bulgarian_ci  and still same ÐšÑƒÐºÐ»Ð¸ Ð·Ð° ÐŸÑ€ÐµÐ¾Ð±Ð»Ð¸Ñ‡Ð°Ð½Ðµ everywhere isBulgarian Language i change this only for Table where is save `name` `id` .... that right ?
in main page on phpmyadmin on right side i see: Database server Server charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)  is that ok ? do i need change this?

Comment: Please [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/21515435/edit) to provide information, do not try to put code in comments. If your collation was `latin1_swedish_ci` when you added the data then it used that charset **when the data was added** so changing it now won't change anything. You have to convert your data to the new charset. Since you have not told us what database you are using, no one can tell you how to do that.

Comment: Sorry i will edit my main topic but that that mean " what database you are using ? "
do you mean if is SQL or Mysql ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could be suffering from a number of different issues related to collation and charset. Most often, cases like this tend to be double-encoding. The phpMyAdmin wiki has information on [resolving these issues](http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/Garbled_data).